# Kendo Angular Grid Filter on UI Value

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo UI for Angular 7 and I have filtering mostly up and working, however there is one thing I can't figure out.  I have a few of my fields that go through pipes to make the UI more user friendly.  For example I have a code in my objects that designates a software; when this is displayed in the grid it transforms the code into the full name of the software to make it easier for the user.

Filtering on this column is working... but it is filtering based on the underlying code, not the UI displayed value.  So the user sees 'Keynote Manager' and tries to put 'Ke' into the filter and it doesn't find anything, because it's looking for 'KM' which is the underlying code.

Is there a way to get it to filter based on the UI displayed/piped value rather than the underlying value before piping?

**Edit**

Not sure if my specific code is really relevant as it's a more general question but here is my code as requested:

*Grid Definition*

```
<kendo-grid [data]="GridData" style="height: 100%" (detailExpand)="GetSessions($event.dataItem)"
                  [reorderable]="true" [resizable]="true"
                  [sortable]="{allowUnsort: true, mode: 'single'}" [sort]="State.sort"
                  [filterable]="true"
                  [filter]="State.filter"
                  (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
                  [loading]="IsLoading">
        <ng-template kendoGridNoRecordsTemplate><div class="values" *ngIf="!IsLoading">No Licenses to Display</div></ng-template>
        <kendo-grid-column title="#" field="Seats" width="60" [filterable]="false"
                           [headerStyle]="{'text-align': 'center'}"
                           [style]="{'text-align': 'center'}"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column title="Software" field="Software">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-license>{{ license.Software | softwareType }}</ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column title="Portable" field="IsPortable" filter="boolean">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-license>{{ license.IsPortable | titlecase }}</ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column title="Features" field="Features">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-license>{{ license.Features | features | titlecase }}</ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column title="Expiry" field="Expiry" filter="date" format="d"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column title="Key" field="ID">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-license>{{ license.ID }}</ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>            
      </kendo-grid>
```

*Component Code*

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {License} from '../Classes/license';
import {LicenseService} from '../license.service';
import {StandaloneActivation} from '../Classes/StandaloneActivation';
import {LicenseUsageBase} from '../Classes/LicenseUsageBase';
import {UserService} from '../user.service';
import {Session} from '../Classes/Session';
import {State, process} from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import {DataStateChangeEvent, GridDataResult} from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-licenses',
  templateUrl: './licenses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./licenses.component.css']
})
export class LicensesComponent implements OnInit {
  // TODO: Allow release of multiple licenses at a time
  Licenses: License[];

  GridData: GridDataResult;

  State: State = {
    skip: 0,
    sort: [{field: 'Software', dir: 'asc'}],
    filter: {
      logic: 'and',
      filters: []
    }
  };
  IsLoading = true;

  constructor(private licenseService: LicenseService,
              private userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetLicenses();
  }

  GetLicenses(): void {
    this.licenseService.GetLicenses().subscribe(licenses => {
      this.Licenses = licenses;
      this.GridData = process(this.Licenses, this.State);
      this.IsLoading = false;
    });
  }   

  public dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
    this.State = state;
    this.GridData = process(this.Licenses, this.State);
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Per the suggestion below I ended up changing my base level converter to set a new property on the class and filtered based on that using my original pipe:

```
private ConvertBaseToLicense(baseObject: any): License {
  const jsonConvert: JsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
  jsonConvert.operationMode = Constants.ConverterMode;

  const license = jsonConvert.deserializeObject<License>(baseObject, License);
  const SwPipe = new SoftwareTypePipe();
  license.UIName = SwPipe.transform(license.Software);
  return license;
}
```

Comment: Add minimum code to get help.

Comment: Added, although it seems a generic case so not sure my code adds too much to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering is going to be against the grid's datasource, but I think there are a couple of ways to achieve what you are looking for, although neither of them is exactly what you want.

The easiest approach would be to modify `GetLicenses()` to add an additional column to your data that contains "Keynote Manager" and the other values either at the source or when the data is returned, and then bind to this column.

Another approach would be to add a [custom filter](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/reusable-filter/) to your grid where you could keep your key value pairs of codes (KM) and friendly descriptions (Keynote Manager) and allow the user to select from a dropdown.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I guess it makes sense that it filters on the data, just was trying figure out how this is handled as it can't be uncommon.  The custom filters looks like a possible good option, I will look into that more.  As far as modifying GetLicenses, it already passes it through json2Typescript to transform the JSON from the API to the correct TypeScript objects, could I just add another extra property there for UIName or something like that?  Sorry I'm coming from C# and not used to adding extra properties to a defined class...

Comment: Cool, that did it.  After trying that, I changed my converter (final code edited into the question). It now sets a new property on the class that is the UI friendly name and the UI filters based on that.  The converter uses my original pipe to set the property instead of just using it in the UI display.  Instead of making it a dynamic property I did make it a full class property, c# habits ingrained :). Thank you!